# SHA1 hash of git object calculated by my program not matching the one from git

Tags: c, sha1

I am writing a C program that would replicate the SHA1 hashes that git gives but the hash it gives keeps changing and never matches the one from git. I don't think anything is wrong with my implementation of SHA1. I tried substituting my implementation with another one but still, get the same results. This is my code:

sha1.h:

```
#ifndef SHA1_H
#define SHA1_H

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t state[5];
    uint32_t count[2];
    unsigned char buffer[64];
} SHA1_CTX;

void SHA1Transform(uint32_t state[5], const unsigned char buffer[64]);

void SHA1Init(SHA1_CTX *context);

void SHA1Update(SHA1_CTX *context, const unsigned char *data, uint32_t len);

void SHA1Final(unsigned char digest[20], SHA1_CTX *context);

void SHA1(char *hash_out, const char *str, int len);

#endif /* _SHA1_H */
```

sha1.c:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "sha1.h"

#define rol(value, bits) (((value) << (bits)) | ((value) >> (32 - (bits))))

/* blk0() and blk() perform the initial expand. */
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define blk0(i) (block->l[i] = (rol(block->l[i], 24) & 0xFF00FF00) | (rol(block->l[i], 8) & 0x00FF00FF))
#elif BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
#define blk0(i) block->l[i]
#else
#error "Endianness not defined!"
#endif
#define blk(i) (block->l[i & 15] = rol(block->l[(i + 13) & 15] ^ block->l[(i + 8) & 15] ^ block->l[(i + 2) & 15] ^ block->l[i & 15], 1))

/* (R0+R1), R2, R3, R4 are the different operations used in SHA1 */
#define R0(v, w, x, y, z, i)                                     \
    z += ((w & (x ^ y)) ^ y) + blk0(i) + 0x5A827999 + rol(v, 5); \
    w = rol(w, 30);
#define R1(v, w, x, y, z, i)                                    \
    z += ((w & (x ^ y)) ^ y) + blk(i) + 0x5A827999 + rol(v, 5); \
    w = rol(w, 30);
#define R2(v, w, x, y, z, i)                            \
    z += (w ^ x ^ y) + blk(i) + 0x6ED9EBA1 + rol(v, 5); \
    w = rol(w, 30);
#define R3(v, w, x, y, z, i)                                          \
    z += (((w | x) & y) | (w & x)) + blk(i) + 0x8F1BBCDC + rol(v, 5); \
    w = rol(w, 30);
#define R4(v, w, x, y, z, i)                            \
    z += (w ^ x ^ y) + blk(i) + 0xCA62C1D6 + rol(v, 5); \
    w = rol(w, 30);

void SHA1Transform(uint32_t state[5], const unsigned char buffer[64])
{
    uint32_t a, b, c, d, e;

    typedef union {
        unsigned char c[64];
        uint32_t l[16];
    } CHAR64LONG16;

    CHAR64LONG16 block[1]; /* use array to appear as a pointer */

    memcpy(block, buffer, 64);
    /* Copy context->state[] to working vars */
    a = state[0];
    b = state[1];
    c = state[2];
    d = state[3];
    e = state[4];
    /* 4 rounds of 20 operations each. Loop unrolled. */
    R0(a, b, c, d, e, 0);
    R0(e, a, b, c, d, 1);
    R0(d, e, a, b, c, 2);
    R0(c, d, e, a, b, 3);
    R0(b, c, d, e, a, 4);
    R0(a, b, c, d, e, 5);
    R0(e, a, b, c, d, 6);
    R0(d, e, a, b, c, 7);
    R0(c, d, e, a, b, 8);
    R0(b, c, d, e, a, 9);
    R0(a, b, c, d, e, 10);
    R0(e, a, b, c, d, 11);
    R0(d, e, a, b, c, 12);
    R0(c, d, e, a, b, 13);
    R0(b, c, d, e, a, 14);
    R0(a, b, c, d, e, 15);
    R1(e, a, b, c, d, 16);
    R1(d, e, a, b, c, 17);
    R1(c, d, e, a, b, 18);
    R1(b, c, d, e, a, 19);
    R2(a, b, c, d, e, 20);
    R2(e, a, b, c, d, 21);
    R2(d, e, a, b, c, 22);
    R2(c, d, e, a, b, 23);
    R2(b, c, d, e, a, 24);
    R2(a, b, c, d, e, 25);
    R2(e, a, b, c, d, 26);
    R2(d, e, a, b, c, 27);
    R2(c, d, e, a, b, 28);
    R2(b, c, d, e, a, 29);
    R2(a, b, c, d, e, 30);
    R2(e, a, b, c, d, 31);
    R2(d, e, a, b, c, 32);
    R2(c, d, e, a, b, 33);
    R2(b, c, d, e, a, 34);
    R2(a, b, c, d, e, 35);
    R2(e, a, b, c, d, 36);
    R2(d, e, a, b, c, 37);
    R2(c, d, e, a, b, 38);
    R2(b, c, d, e, a, 39);
    R3(a, b, c, d, e, 40);
    R3(e, a, b, c, d, 41);
    R3(d, e, a, b, c, 42);
    R3(c, d, e, a, b, 43);
    R3(b, c, d, e, a, 44);
    R3(a, b, c, d, e, 45);
    R3(e, a, b, c, d, 46);
    R3(d, e, a, b, c, 47);
    R3(c, d, e, a, b, 48);
    R3(b, c, d, e, a, 49);
    R3(a, b, c, d, e, 50);
    R3(e, a, b, c, d, 51);
    R3(d, e, a, b, c, 52);
    R3(c, d, e, a, b, 53);
    R3(b, c, d, e, a, 54);
    R3(a, b, c, d, e, 55);
    R3(e, a, b, c, d, 56);
    R3(d, e, a, b, c, 57);
    R3(c, d, e, a, b, 58);
    R3(b, c, d, e, a, 59);
    R4(a, b, c, d, e, 60);
    R4(e, a, b, c, d, 61);
    R4(d, e, a, b, c, 62);
    R4(c, d, e, a, b, 63);
    R4(b, c, d, e, a, 64);
    R4(a, b, c, d, e, 65);
    R4(e, a, b, c, d, 66);
    R4(d, e, a, b, c, 67);
    R4(c, d, e, a, b, 68);
    R4(b, c, d, e, a, 69);
    R4(a, b, c, d, e, 70);
    R4(e, a, b, c, d, 71);
    R4(d, e, a, b, c, 72);
    R4(c, d, e, a, b, 73);
    R4(b, c, d, e, a, 74);
    R4(a, b, c, d, e, 75);
    R4(e, a, b, c, d, 76);
    R4(d, e, a, b, c, 77);
    R4(c, d, e, a, b, 78);
    R4(b, c, d, e, a, 79);
    /* Add the working vars back into context.state[] */
    state[0] += a;
    state[1] += b;
    state[2] += c;
    state[3] += d;
    state[4] += e;
    /* Wipe variables */
    a = b = c = d = e = 0;
    memset(block, '\0', sizeof(block));
}

void SHA1Init(SHA1_CTX *context)
{
    /* SHA1 initialization constants */
    context->state[0] = 0x67452301;
    context->state[1] = 0xEFCDAB89;
    context->state[2] = 0x98BADCFE;
    context->state[3] = 0x10325476;
    context->state[4] = 0xC3D2E1F0;
    context->count[0] = context->count[1] = 0;
}

void SHA1Update(SHA1_CTX *context, const unsigned char *data, uint32_t len)
{
    uint32_t i;

    uint32_t j;

    j = context->count[0];
    if ((context->count[0] += len << 3) < j)
        context->count[1]++;
    context->count[1] += (len >> 29);
    j = (j >> 3) & 63;
    if ((j + len) > 63) {
        memcpy(&context->buffer[j], data, (i = 64 - j));
        SHA1Transform(context->state, context->buffer);
        for (; i + 63 < len; i += 64) {
            SHA1Transform(context->state, &data[i]);
        }
        j = 0;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    memcpy(&context->buffer[j], &data[i], len - i);
}

void SHA1Final(unsigned char digest[20], SHA1_CTX *context)
{
    unsigned i;

    unsigned char finalcount[8];

    unsigned char c;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        finalcount[i] = (unsigned char)((context->count[(i >= 4 ? 0 : 1)] >> ((3 - (i & 3)) * 8)) & 255); /* Endian independent */
    c = 0200;
    SHA1Update(context, &c, 1);
    while ((context->count[0] & 504) != 448) {
        c = 0000;
        SHA1Update(context, &c, 1);
    }
    SHA1Update(context, finalcount, 8); /* Should cause a SHA1Transform() */
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        digest[i] = (unsigned char)((context->state[i >> 2] >> ((3 - (i & 3)) * 8)) & 255);
    /* Wipe variables */
    memset(context, '\0', sizeof(*context));
    memset(&finalcount, '\0', sizeof(finalcount));
}

void SHA1(char *hash_out, const char *str, int len)
{
    SHA1_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char *hash = malloc(20);

    SHA1Init(&ctx);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1)
        SHA1Update(&ctx, (const unsigned char *)str + i, 1);
    SHA1Final(hash, &ctx);

    /* Convert to hex */
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        sprintf(hash_out + i * 2, "%02x", hash[i]);
}
```

object hash function:

```
char *object_hash(struct object *object)
{
    /* Get size of object */
    int size = object->size;
    /* Size to string */
    char *sizeStr = malloc(20);
    sprintf(sizeStr, "%d", size);
    size += strlen(objectTypeStrings[object->type]);
    size += strlen(sizeStr);
    size += 2;
    char *format = malloc(size + 1);
    sprintf(format, "%s %s\0%s", objectTypeStrings[object->type], sizeStr, object->data);
    /* Get hash of object */
    char *hash = calloc(41, sizeof(char));
    SHA1(hash, format, size);
    free(format);
    free(sizeStr);
    return hash;
}
```

other relevant things:

```
enum objectType {
    commit,
    tree,
    blob,
    tag
};

struct object {
    enum objectType type;
    int size;
    char *data;
};

char *objectTypeStrings[] = {
    "commit",
    "tree",
    "blob",
    "tag"
};
```

all code here: https://github.com/arnavbhate/avcs

Comment: Have you checked the end-of-line settings for the repo (https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)?  Depending on how you have things configured, it may be converting the EOL between LF and CRLF, which would affect the SHA-1.

Comment: @JonathonS. The file is in LF and hash is checked with `git hash-object`. Repo does not have any such settings. I created the repo and my global config file has `autocrlf = input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More robust solution would be to use SHA1Init() and subsequent SHA1Update() calls for the data, ending with SHA1Finish(). Current approach would be slow as hashes data byte-by-byte in SHA1() function call.
I.e. something like the following:

```
char *object_hash(struct object *object)
{
    SHA1_CTX ctx;
    SHA1Init(&ctx);
    /* Size to string */
    char sizeStr[20] = {0};
    snprintf(sizeStr, sizeof(sizeStr), "%d", object->size);
    SHA1Update(&ctx, (const uint8_t *) objectTypeStrings[object->type], strlen(objectTypeStrings[object->type]);
    SHA1Update(&ctx, (const uint8_t *) " ", 1);
    SHA1Update(&ctx, (const uint8_t *) sizeStr, strlen(sizeStr));
    SHA1Update(&ctx, (const uint8_t *) "", 1);
    SHA1Update(&ctx, (const uint8_t *) object->data, object->size);

    /* Get hash of object */
    unsigned char hash[20] = {0};
    SHA1Final(hash, &ctx);

    /* Convert to hex */
    char *hash_out = calloc(41, sizeof(char));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        sprintf(hash_out + i * 2, "%02x", hash[i]);
    return hash_out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format string has a literal NUL (`'\0'`) in it, so your last argument (the data) isn't being added (since C strings end at the first NUL).

If you want `sprintf` to append the NUL, you'll have to use `%c` and pass `'\0'` as an argument (though as `sprintf` is already putting a null at the end of the string, you don't actually need to).

You should also note that arbitrary files may include NUL characters in the data, which will be truncated by `sprintf` when passed as `%s`.
I'd suggest that you `memcpy` your data in, instead of using `sprintf` for this purpose.

(Also, you can avoid calling `strlen` on your size string, since `sprintf` returns the number of characters printed, excluding the terminating NUL)

I'll also add that as shown by @Nickolay Olshevsky, you don't actually need to copy your data into the same buffer, you can just feed the hash with your header, followed by the data.

Comment: I didn't know about `sprintf`. While I will use @Nickolay Olshevsky 's method for finding the hash, I will still use this when writing the object.